# Element with padding moving on hover

Tags: css

I have an `a` element. On hover I am adding outline and outline offset and additional padding. The problem is that the element moves on hover.

html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="link">test</a>
```

css

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
  //  margin: 1px 1px;
}

.link:hover {
    outline: 0.125rem dotted red;
    color: black;
    outline-offset: -1px;
    padding: 1px 1px;
      //  margin: 0;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pbk9djp/116/

The two ways I have found are:

1. margin on normal state equal to the padding on hover and then margin 0 on hover
2. the padding to be on the normal state, not on the hover

I definitely do not like the first scenario. If I have no other choice, I will go for the second.

Any ideas for something else?

Comment: Any particular reason why you will not go with option #2? To me it seems like the solution to your problem.

Comment: The reason is that I am changing the default behavior while I am fixing this issue but after all, I decided to go with this as it seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding on normal state is fine, but an alternative way is to use a negative `translateX` and `translateY`, e.g.

```
.link:hover {
    ...
    padding: 1px 1px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
    -o-transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px);
}
```

2d transformation are [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (even from IE9)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5pbk9djp/117/

Comment: Very nice solution. One problem I found is if there are two link the other is moving: http://jsfiddle.net/5pbk9djp/122/. Do You have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I am going with my second solution with the padding but thanks for the interesting proposal. You are getting the points from that answer.

Answer (score 0):

with this you don't care of browser compatibility, all prefixes -moz, -webkit... not needed

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.link:hover {
    outline: 0.125rem dotted red;
    color: black;
    outline-offset: -1px;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/b7s4d89x/